# Erlang: Value of attribute 'xmlns' not extracted while parsing xml using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, erlang, xml-namespaces

I am trying to parse the following xml: `<<"<message xmlns=\"jabber:client\" to=\"test1@kushdev.ssqueal.org/20500423901404388005197218/Gajim\" type=\"chat\" id=\"66\"><body>as</body><x xmlns=\"jabber:x:event\"><composing /></x><thread>eJFMuziLDXZIdeWRvUCdjPfyIZJoucVE</thread></message>">>` .

To find the value of the 'xmlns' attribute I am using  `xmerl_xpath:string("//x/@xmlns", Root).` or `xmerl_xpath:string("//message/@xmlns", Root).` 
In both cases a empty list is returned, though this approach is working fine in case of other attributes. I am aware of the special status of the xmlns attr, but should'nt it's value be extracted like any other attribute?

What am I doing wrong here and is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

In the XPath data model, namespaces are a different kind of node from attributes. You can get the value using the namespace axis rather than the attribute axis, but in this case, what you probably really want is the namespace URI of the root element of the document, which is delivered by the XPath expression `namespace-uri(/*)`